# Exclude Mongo fields based on regex

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, robo3t, nosql

My collection has 1000s of fields and I would like to exclude fields that match a certain regex. Several hundred fields are in the form: 'label**XXXX**', where XXXX is 4 integers. Is this possible?

(i.e. How would I exclude fields from the collection which match 'label**XXXX**' from my query?)

Comment: do you want to remove all the values containing `labelXXXX`

Comment: yes, remove all fields and their values.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using $not in mongodb

```
    {
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "label123"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "name" : "sample"
}


db.getCollection('things').find({name:{$not:/^label/}})
```

> Output:{
>           "_id" : "2",
>           "name" : "sample"
>       }